# How to learn OpenGL 3.x using C?

Tags: c, opengl, cross-platform

I know there are *many* tutorials on OpenGL out there, but all good tutorials I found use some C++ libraries (mostly GLM) that make it hard to follow for people that would like to use C, or/and were specific to Microsoft Windows.

My Questions are:

1. Does anybody know a good OpenGL 3.x tutorial that uses C and is not Windows specific?
2. Which programming language does the OpenGL "redbook" use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does anybody know a good OpenGL 3.x tutorial that uses C and is not Windows specific?

If I remember correctly, [Nicol Bolas's tutorials](https://web.archive.org/web/20140209181347/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) use C++ (for GLM). I suggest you replace GLM with my [linmath.h](https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h) where applicable.

> Which programming language does the OpenGL "redbook" use?

The older editions (<= OpenGL-2.1) used pure C. The newer ones I actually didn't read.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I hope that "linmath" will be the solution to my C++ problems.

Comment: After scouring all over the internet, I finally found someone who is recommending a good C math library for OpenGL! Thankssssss been looking for one

Comment: this is great, swapping glm.h for linmath.h dropped my compile time from 350ms to 70ms

Comment: @racarate: Thanks. Please report all issues you're experiencing with linmath.h – I'll have to implement a more efficient matrix inversion eventually, though. It's not a hard problem…